# How to insert a System.Drawing.Image as a Metafile into a Word document?

Tags: c#, image, ms-word, insert, metafile

I have a problem with metafile picture insertion into a Word document from code.  I need to insert picture already loaded as a **`System.Drawing.Image`**, not from path. The method:

```
InlineShapes.AddPicture("picture path", etc...)
```

won't work.

I tried to use the `Paste()` method, but it throws exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Command error

```
Image image = Image.FromFile("path");
Word.Range range = selection.Range;
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.MetafilePicture, image);
selection.Range.Paste(); // throws exception
```

How can I do this?

Hopefully solution has found, thanks for @Jimi! I did a mistake:

not

```
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.MetafilePicture, image)
```

but

```
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.EnhancedMetafile, image)
```

Comment: `Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, image);`. Btw, you have a typo here, `DataFormats.MetafilePicture`: it's `MetafilePict` or `EnhancedMetafile`. But, you'ld have to produce one.

Comment: @Jimi, thankyou, now all works fine.